# Is it possible to use the lambert w function to find the real solution to this equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, lambert-w

In the equation:
$$b^b = \frac{1}{256}$$
There is a clear real solution, $b=-4$. Is it possible to find this solution using the lambert W function? This is what I have tried so far:
$$ b^b = \frac{1}{256} $$
$$b\ln(b) = -\ln(256)$$
$$\ln(b)e^{\ln(b)} = -\ln(256)$$
$$\ln(b) = W(-\ln(256))$$
$$b = e^{W(-\ln(256))}$$
This is a solution but I want to find the real solution. Is that possible without just guessing?

Comment: The function $y=x^x$ is well-defined over the negative numbers only for integer values of $x$. To me, using any calculus seems cumbersome.

Comment: Right, we usually don't define $b^b$ for $b\leq 0,$ even when $b$ is an integer. Exponentiation becomes quite messy if we do.

Comment: I'll add that "finding a solution in terms of $W$" may not be too useful because evaluating $W$ itself is hard. If you're in some specific situation where a "closed form" that includes $W$ is still valuable to you, then you should edit the question to add more context explaining what that situation is, so answerers can figure out what would be useful to you.